# Is good way decrypt password in application?

Tags: .net, security, encryption, password-encryption

i thinking about problem with decrypt password in application.
For example:
I encrypt password with key (which is save in application) and save encryph to database.
And if i login to application I load encrypt from database and with same key decrypt to password and equal with user password which wrote to textboxt for example.

It is good way?
I think its bad way, because if somebody lost source code, that all passwords are in dangerous. Is better use for example Identity for .NET or write own solution?

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: The problem is that you are thinking about decrypt password.  Secure authentication does not involve decrypt.  Use a library.

Comment: You say "encrypt" and then you say "hash", the two are not entirely compatible. Can you please clarify what it is that you mean? You cannot decrypt a hash, at all (if you can, it is not a hash value).

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I think encrypt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store passwords the right way, you need 3 things:

1. Only store the user's password hashed

   Why: now you do not know the password, nor do you have an easy way to find it anymore either. If you cannot, your attacker also will have more trouble.

   Obviously you want to chose a hash algorithm that's not to be considered broken in itself.
2. Use a long random salt per user, you can even change the salt every time you change the password

   The salt prevents the use of an attack technique that uses precomputed hashes of well known passwords (like "password", "letmein" etc.). This is critical to do right. Chose long salts and chose them randomly. You can store the salt along with the hash, that's not a problem.
3. Use a SLOW hash.

   This is one many people who roll their own solution miss. The best known hash algorithms are designed to be fast. If you use a fast algorithm, attackers using GPU farms can still break about 95% of passwords users commonly pick using dictionary attacks.

   So you need to chose an algorithm that's as slow as you can bear. Using one round of SHA-1, SHA-2 or even SHA-3 is not good enough to be a real challenge.

Then there's rule 0:
NEVER INVENT YOUR OWN CRYPTO

The reason is that you will not get peer review from knowledgeable people. You really want that vetting to have occurred as mistakes are easy to make, and have terrible consequences.

Hence 
- Use a library and 
- use it properly: pick a slow hash designed for storing passwords, and set the parameters to make it as slow as you can bear.

To verify a password entered by a user:

- you get the plaintext password from the user,
- you retrieve the salt and the stored hash from your database
- you compute the hash of the salt+plaintext
- you compare it to the hash retrieved from the database:

  - if it matches: the password is good,
  - if it does not match, the password was wrong.

Comment: Add: The best candidates for slow hash are scrypt, bcrypt, pbkdf2.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. Only ever store salted and hashed versions of passwords. Do **not** store an encrypted version of the password.

The correct procedure is to store the salted and hashed version of the password. When a user tries to log in, retrieve the salt for the username that they entered and use it to salt and hash the password that the user entered. Compare that to the salted and hashed version in the database.

And definitely use a library. **Never** roll your own password-hashing code. This is how many, if not most, of the major password leaks that you hear about in the news happened.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is bad. The best way is to use some library that has some encryption algorithm. In this way you are sure you did good.